# Webots cannot download objects and textures

Tags: webots

After installing the newest version of Webots, I find that the objects (PROTO) and textures of the scene cannot be downloaded. The console throws many errors about download failures and the 3D scene misses objects. It may come from a local firewall problem preventing Webots to download the textures. Is it possible to get a local copy of the Webots resources (PROTO files and textures) to avoid this problem and run Webots off-line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, firewalls may prevent Webots to download the resources.

In this case, you can download and install manually the Webots assets (PROTO files, textures, etc.) using the instructions described here:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/installation-procedure#asset-cache-download

Once installed, Webots won't download the textures and other resources from the Internet, but use the ones cached locally.

The assets for the latest version Webots R2023a can be downloaded as [ZIP archive](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/releases/download/R2023a/assets-R2023a.zip) (named `assets-R2023a.zip`) from the GitHub download page of Webots:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/releases/tag/R2023a

*Disclaimer: I am a software developer at Webots.*