# Trouble downloading assets in Windows version 2023a

Tags: webots

I'm trying to load a world on Webots, but I've been having trouble downloading the required assets.

Whenever I load the desired world, a pop-up appears saying "Downloading assets 0%", before getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: Error downloading EXTERNPROTO 'CorrodedMetal': Cannot download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/50c3f419b5da49a2af606297049ee91e8adbc92e/projects/appearances/protos/CorrodedMetal.proto', error code: 5: Operation canceled
ERROR: Error downloading EXTERNPROTO 'Wall': Cannot download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/50c3f419b5da49a2af606297049ee91e8adbc92e/projects/objects/apartment_structure/protos/Wall.proto', error code: 5: Operation canceled
ERROR: File 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/50c3f419b5da49a2af606297049ee91e8adbc92e/projects/objects/apartment_structure/protos/Wall.proto' is not readable.
ERROR: File 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/50c3f419b5da49a2af606297049ee91e8adbc92e/projects/appearances/protos/CorrodedMetal.proto' is not readable.
ERROR: 'C:/Users/OBR/Downloads/erebus-v23.0.5/game/protos/worldTile.proto':53:23: error: Skipped unknown 'CorrodedMetal' node or PROTO.
ERROR: 'C:/Users/OBR/Downloads/erebus-v23.0.5/game/protos/worldTile.proto':53:23: error: Skipped unknown 'CorrodedMetal' node or PROTO.
INFO: MainSupervisor: Starting controller: python.exe -u MainSupervisor.py
```

I've tried disabling my firewall already, but the error doesn't go away.
It's worth noting that I have a computer company, which might have some network-mandated firewall (I am not sure if this is relevant).

Comment: download the file using a web browser and examine it

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem is likely caused by a firewall. To work around the issue, I recommend that you download the assets as explained in [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/24108/17975).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*